# Needing Support Configuring OpenVPN Road Warrior - Locking Down SSH To That VPN

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I have installed `https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install` onto my dedicated machine, and I need to lock down SSH connections to this system. I have attempted to configure `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the `Listen Address: 10.8.0.1` address and `ListenAddress 10.8.0.0` but unfortunately this does lock down the connection, but I am unable to connect after the VPN is enabled. Unfortunately it throws `Connection Refused` with SSH connections.

This is the top configuration of my OVPN file, please let me know what I need to edit so I A: Get the VPN to work (It does work and connects sucessfully, but not routing traffic through it I believe, which is why it will not allow me to connect (Basically forcing my connection via the server I think, not too sure though if that's the cause)) and B: Have I got the `ListenAddress` configured correctly? Which IP do I need to allow? .1 or .0 on the `10.8.0.x` address. If I get this correct, I just need to fix the VPN file, and then we are good to connect basically and lock it down to VPN authentication.

Server IP Configuration: (Configured By OVPN I presume)
https://jasmeow.pics/CKF7TX.png

````
dev tun
proto udp
remote <IPREDACTED> <PORTREDACTED>
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>```
````

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "locking down SSH"? You want to be able to connect to the RW system using SSH only through the VPN? You want RW to only be able to connect to the VPN server through VPN? Anyway, in both cases you will not achieve this by setting the address where SSH is listening. Binding to some address doesn't limit the source of the connection to be behind that interface. Use a firewall properly for that.

Comment: Something made me thinking that you believe this ListenAddress directive limits the source of the connection to that address. It doesn't, this is absolutely different thing.

Comment: Hi Guys - What I mean is I would like to do is basically lock down SSH by connecting first the RW VPN connection, it connects, then I can then SSH into the system. If I don't use the VPN, no connection to the dedicated server via SSH, simple right? What do I do to get this sorted properly?

Comment: I want to limit the connection to only be allowed via VPN. I can setup the firewall to block SSH connections except from the VPN IP, but how do I do this successfully? How do I allow SSH authentication from only the VPN's IP address is what I am asking. I believed the ListenAddress directive limits the source of the connection, yes, but it seems that's not the case, and thank you for pointing that out to me Nikita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using legacy IPTables, you may use rule like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 ! -s 10.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

With modern NFTables, you have to use something like this one:

```
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT ip saddr != 10.8.0.0/24 tcp dport 22 counter reject
```

(provided that you already instantiated a table filter of type inet and chain INPUT in it).

This is quite generic low-level, and won't persist. To have this to survive the reboot, you need to use some firewall configuration manager; in Debian I usually installed the `netfilter-persistent` and `iptables-persistent`. In case you already have firewall manager (`firewalld`, `ufw` and so on), you need to use the methods corresponding to these managers instead.

---

Also notice that SSH itself is no less secure than VPN if properly configured. By proper configuration I mean configuring the RSA/ECDSA/etc. key authentication (which is usually already configured by default, you only need to generate and install keys), and then disabling the password authentication in SSH:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Such setup is much convenient to use and also much simpler than VPN+firewall, but no less secure. Also it is harder to misconfigure. Consider this approach.

Comment: Thank you for this, this does really help. What about UFW?
SSH Keys are enabled - Rest assured about that.